# KeyError issue with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, keyerror

Im using a dictionary in my code and comparing the user's input to it, but when the user input nothing and just hits enter the program falls over and gives me a key error. I tried to use 'Try and Except' but that way the the program loops to the beginning which i dont want, i want to keep the program in the sub loop until the user inputs something that is within the boundary.

```
ftablet=open("tablet.txt").readlines() devicelist=["phone","tablet"]

dtablet = {}

for line in ftablet:
       (key,val) = line.split(":")
       dtablet[str(key)] = val.strip(",")    

while True:    
   counter=0    
   device=""

   while device not in (devicelist):
      device=input(What is your device?: ").lower().replace(" ","")
      print()


   if device == "tablet": 
      usermodel=""

      while usermodel != (dtablet["phonemodels"]): 
         print(dtablet["modelquestion"])
         usermodel=input("Enter MODEL Here: ").lower().replace(" ","")

         if usermodel in (dtablet["phonemodels"]):
            name=""

            while name != (dtablet[usermodel]):
               print(dtablet["namequestion"])
               print("Enter any of these : ",(dtablet[model]))
               name=input("Enter NAME Here: ").upper().replace(" ","")

               if name in (dtablet[usermodel]):
                  storage=""

                  while storage != (dtablet[name]):
                     print(dtablet["storagequestion"])
                     print("Enter any of these : ",(dtablet[name]))
                     storage=input("Enter STORAGE Here: ").upper().replace(" ","")

                     if storage in (dtablet[name]):
                        problem=input("What is the PROBLEM with your tablet?\nEnter Here: ").upper()
                        print()

                        for word in problem.split():
                           if word in (dtablet[storage]):
                              print(dtablet[word])
                              print("Thanks for using my troubleshooting program")
                              counter=1
                        if counter==0:
                           print("We dont have your keyword in out database")
   else:
      print("Sorry! We do not have that device in out database please choose from the ones listed above.")
```

This is My Text file that i converted into a dictionary which is called 'dtablet'.

> modelquestion:What is the Model of your Tablet?
>
> namequestion:What is the Name of your Tablet?
>
> storagequestion:What is the STORAGE of your Tablet?
>
> problemquestion:What is the PROBLEM with your Tablet?
>
> phonemodels:apple,samsung,sony
>
> apple:IPAD1,IPAD2,IPAD3
>
> samsung:TAB1,TAB2,TAB3
>
> sony:XPERIAZ2,XPERIAZ3,XPERIAZ4
>
> IPAD1:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> IPAD2:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> IPAD3:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> TAB1:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> TAB2:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> TAB3:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> XPERIAZ1:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> XPERIAZ2:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> XPERIAZ3:16GB,32GB,64GB
>
> 16GB:cracked,broken
>
> 32GB:cracked,broken
>
> 64GB:cracked,broken
>
> CRACKED:Problem = Cracked Solution = Take your phone to the repair
>   shop
>
> BROKEN:Problem = Broken Solution = Take your phone to the repair shop

Comment: Providing the entire traceback might be helpful.

Comment: @Arpan the highlighting only works when the question is properly tagged with the [tag:python] tag.  There is a pending edit adding it.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a key `"model"` what if you print out `dtable.keys()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have both

```
dtablet[model]   # the key is the model variable
```

and

```
dtablet["model"] # the key is the "model" string
```

in your code, is this intentional?

If a user presses 'enter' then `model` will be an empty string, and this expression:

```
model in dtablet[model]
```

will always be true if dtablet[model] is a string.

Comment: yes this is intentional because "model" is a key which i know of where as model will be assigned by the users input.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you haven't included quotation marks around the key `"model"`. This means that it wouldn't locate it anyway.

Also, why don't you just keep it to one loop? It'd be far more efficient.

Comment: but then how would i validate the inputs if i keep it in one loop ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have a "model" key in your dictionary. You can print out `dtablet.keys()` and find if there is "model" in there. If not, then dtablet["model"] will 100% returns a KeyError.

Second, when you type `while model != (dtablet["model"]):`, since `model` is an empty string and if dtablet["model"] is a string then it will not go inside the while loop because an empty string is always a substring of any string.

Comment: Ive added in my dictionary and my whole code which will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I can clearly see that there's no "model" from the left `:` of your txt file, so dtablet["model"] doesn't exist.

Comment: I changed the variable names and key names to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You do realise that the `while` loop has both a `break` option and a `continue` option?
If you "want to keep the program in the sub loop until the user inputs something that is within the boundary" test and `continue` if the input was not what you were looking for.

Comment: so should i put continue after every while loop ?